# Sending SMTP emails using PHPMailer via Kimsufi Server

Tags: php, email, smtp, debian, phpmailer

I have a [Kimsufi](https://www.kimsufi.com/en/) (OVH) server with Debian.

I want to use the [PHPMailer library](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to send SMTP emails.

I have no idea what the username and password should be.

```
    $this->mail->isSMTP();               // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $this->mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $this->mail->Host = 'my server ip';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;        // Enable SMTP authentication
    $this->mail->Username = '';          // SMTP username
    $this->mail->Password = '';          // SMTP password
    $this->mail->SMTPSecure = '';        // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $this->mail->Port = 25;              // TCP port to connect to
```

How can I get the required username and password?

Answer (score 0):

Username and password would be the sender email details. It is asking through which email address you would like to send mails via phpmailer. Since phpmailer library require SMTP username & password to send out mail and to confirm the inbox delivery. Not only that it also require SMTP server & authentication details.

Let's use personal gmail account to send mail via phpmailer in that case your code would be like this

```
$this->mail->isSMTP();               // Set mailer to use SMTP
$this->mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$this->mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;        // Enable SMTP authentication
$this->mail->Username = 'gmailemail@gmail.com';          // SMTP username
$this->mail->Password = 'yourgmailpassword';          // SMTP password
$this->mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';        // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$this->mail->Port = 587;              // TCP port to connect to
```

Comment: Thanks @Sachin, but I don't want to use a personal mail account to send emails. I want to use my dedicated server. It is the problem.

Comment: If you would like to use email address with your domain then create a email address under that domain and set the username and password instead of google one. Or let me know domain will give you all info to use